# SvelteKit cannot import Onboard.js

Tags: javascript, svelte, rollup, vite, sveltekit

I am working on a SvelteKit project and have installed [Onboard.js](https://docs.blocknative.com/onboard):

I am using the [`pnpm`](https://pnpm.io/) package manager, but it shouldn't make a difference:

```
pnpm install bnc-onboard
```

```
// __layout.svelte
import Onboard from "bnc-onboard";
```

When I start my development server, I get the following module resolution errors (not all have been included):

```
pnpm run dev
```

[image]

How can I fix this?

**Edit**: I tried following these [rollup instructions](https://docs.blocknative.com/onboard#rollup-builds). Since SvelteKit uses Vite, which is based on Rollup, I tried adding the following to `svelte.config.js`:

```
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json'
import nodePolyfills from 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills'

// ...

export default {
  // ...
  kit: {
    // ...
    vite: {
       plugins: [
            json(),
            resolve({
                browser: true,
                preferBuiltins: true
            }),
            commonjs({
                namedExports: {
                    "u2f-api": ["sign", "isSupported"]
                },
            }),
            nodePolyfills(),
        ],
    },
  },
};
```

This did not help. I am getting the exact same error.

**Edit 2**: It appears the `bnc-onboard` package never installed correctly in the first place. I made [another question about this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69319580/npm-error-installing-onboard-js-package-on-windows), and I'll update this question once I fix that.

**Edit 3**: I got the above solved. Now I'm getting this slightly different error:

[image]

**Edit 4**: I ran `pnpm install @keystonehq/bc-ur-registry`, I am now getting the following error instead:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `pnpm install @keystonehq/bc-ur-registry`?

Comment: @hackape It seems that might have partially fixed the problem thanks. Now I'm on to the next error.

Comment: I write it as a comment but **I think** it will not work because of `crypto`. If you head to the readme of `rollup-plugin-node-polyfills` it say `Crypto is not shimmed and and we just provide the commonjs one from browserify and it will likely not work`.
You can try `nodePolyfills({ buffer: true, crypto: true })` and `resolve: { browser: true }` but I had no luck.