# NPM error installing Onboard.js package on Windows

Tags: windows, npm

I am trying to install [Onboard.js](https://docs.blocknative.com/onboard) on Windows using the following command:

```
npm i bnc-onboard
```

This is failing with the following error:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: `node-pre-gyp` is not available on your PC, try to install it globally, so `npm install -g node-pre-gyp` might help.

Comment: @MilanTenk Great thanks. That seems to have worked! Feel free to leave that as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `node-pre-gyp` is not installed on the PC, installing it with `npm install -g node-pre-gyp` command solves the issue.